# What does "to himself" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Then he called one of his lords-in-waiting, who was so high-bred, that when any in an inferior rank **to himself** spoke to him, or asked him a question, he would answer, “Pooh,” which means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite grammatical. It should say

*in an inferior rank to his own*

It means that when this high-born lord-in-waiting was spoken to by **those of lower rank**, he treated them with contempt.

Comment: Doesn't the sentence give the same meaning in this way? Then he called one of his lords-in-waiting, who was so high-bred, that when any in an inferior rank spoke to him, or asked him a question, he would answer, “Pooh,” which means nothing.

Comment: Yes, you've got it.